# How can I enable/disable a script that is attached to a character, only once?

Tags: unity, c#

With only once, I mean once false and once true. The reason I want to enable and disable the script is that I don't want to disable the player controller and then after some point re-enable that controller again.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;

public class FadeScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public FirstPersonController fpc;
    public float fadeDuration = 5;
    public float speed;

    private Material material;
    private float targetAlpha = 0;
    private float lerpParam;
    private float startAlpha = 1;

    void Start()
    {
        material = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
        SetMaterialAlpha(1);

        fpc.enabled = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        lerpParam += Time.deltaTime;

        float alpha = Mathf.Lerp(startAlpha, targetAlpha, lerpParam / fadeDuration);
        SetMaterialAlpha(alpha);

        if (alpha == 0)
        {
            fpc.enabled = true;
            var firstpc = fpc.GetComponent<FirstPersonController>();

            if (fpc.transform.rotation != Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0))
            {
                firstpc.enabled = false;
                fpc.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(fpc.transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0), speed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            if (fpc.transform.rotation == Quaternion.Euler(0,0,0))
            {
                firstpc.enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void FadeTo(float alpha, float duration)
    {
        startAlpha = material.color.a;
        targetAlpha = alpha;
        fadeDuration = duration;
        lerpParam = 0;
    }

    private void SetMaterialAlpha(float alpha)
    {
        Color color = material.color;
        color.a = alpha;
        material.color = color;
    }
}
```

This script is not attached to the `FirstPersonController`. That is why I added the global variable fpc.

I'm getting the script that is already attached to the fpc. I called it firstpc and the script name is: `FirstPersonController`

`FirstPersonController` gives the player a control over the fpc with the mouse camera. I want to disable the script until `fpc.transform.rotation == Quaternion.Euler(0,0,0)` and then enabled the script again to use.

The problem is that it's all the time getting over and over again to the line:

```
firstpc.enabled = false;
```

Then it's getting also to the line:

```
firstpc.enabled = true;
```

But since it's getting to the false all the time it's stuck between both states.

[image: fpc]

The script here in my question is attached to the Plane in the hierarchy.
And the script I want to enable/disable is attached to the `FPSController`.

In my script that is attached to the Plane, `fpc` is the `FPSController` and `firstpc` is the script `FirstPersonController` that attached to the `fpc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using a bool helper: rotated

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;

public class FadeScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public FirstPersonController fpc;
    public float fadeDuration = 5;
    public float speed;

    private Material material;
    private float targetAlpha = 0;
    private float lerpParam;
    private float startAlpha = 1;
    private bool rotated = false;

    void Start()
    {
        material = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
        SetMaterialAlpha(1);

        fpc.enabled = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        lerpParam += Time.deltaTime;

        float alpha = Mathf.Lerp(startAlpha, targetAlpha, lerpParam / fadeDuration);
        SetMaterialAlpha(alpha);

        if (alpha == 0)
        {
            fpc.enabled = true;

            if (rotated == false)
            {
                fpc.GetComponent<FirstPersonController>().enabled = false;
                fpc.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(fpc.transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0), speed * Time.deltaTime);
            }

            if (fpc.transform.localRotation == Quaternion.Euler(0,0,0))
            {
                fpc.GetComponent<FirstPersonController>().enabled = true;
                rotated = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void FadeTo(float alpha, float duration)
    {
        startAlpha = material.color.a;
        targetAlpha = alpha;
        fadeDuration = duration;
        lerpParam = 0;
    }

    private void SetMaterialAlpha(float alpha)
    {
        Color color = material.color;
        color.a = alpha;
        material.color = color;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the engine uses global variables, start the script off with a conditional statement that checks for whether the statement that uses Boolean is true. If so, then use :

```
If (Bool1 == true) {
(have statements to be executed here.)
}
```